# Period of recurring decimals Euler

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is it always true that the period $d$ of $1/n$ when it is a recurring decimal (not recurring of 0’s or 9’s) divides $\phi (n) $?

I can see that if $n$ is coprime to 10 then $10^{\phi (n)} \equiv 1 \mod n $ but what about when $n$ is not coprime to 10?

Comment: The Euler totient function is [multiplicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function), so yes: you can take out the powers of $2$ and $5$, use your result and then put them back.  It is probably sensible to say that the period of numbers of the form $\frac{1}{2^n5^m}$ have period $1$ to avoid division by $0$

Comment: Can we deduce the period of $\frac{1}{2n} $ or $\frac{1}{5n} $ if we know the period of $\frac{1}{n} $? If so, how?

Comment: I would have thought it must be the same period.  The period of $\frac1{2n}$ is the same as the period of $\frac5n$ which is the same as the period of $\frac1n$

Comment: I would have thought the same thing but how to prove?

Comment: Perhaps something like saying the period of $\frac ab$ is the period of $\frac pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are coprime and $pb=qa$.  The period of $\frac pq$ must divide the period of $\frac 1q$ (multiply the decimal expansion of $\frac 1q$ by $p$) while the period of $\frac pq$ must be divisible by the period of $\frac 1q$ (multiply the decimal expansion of $\frac pq$ by the multiplicative inverse of $p \bmod q$).  There is probably a neater way