# Period of recurring decimals not coprime to 10

Tags: number-theory

If we have $1/n$ which is a recurring decimal (not recurring with 0’s or 9’s) where $n$ is coprime to 10, is the period of $\frac{1}{2n} $ and $\frac{1}{5n} $ the same as the period of $\frac{1}{n} $. I think it should be the case but don’t know how to show it. Is this true and how can I show it?

Comment: Show that the eventual period of a rational $r$ has order dividing $k$ If and only if $(10^k-1)10^m r$ is an integer for some $m$.

Comment: Yes I can see that this is true. How does it help? I actually already thought of this but couldn’t see how to use it.

Comment: If you already thought of it, you should have mentioned it in your question. People are more likely to help if you show that you have made an effort!

Comment: Related to a comment in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4379119/period-of-recurring-decimals-euler